# C# 'set' that only raises an event

Tags: c#, events, recursion, properties, setter

I would like to have a public property that can be both got / set. But I would also like an NameChanged event to be triggered when it is set, but I do not want to have a non-public field to store its value.

My problem is, within a setter, how can I assign the property with the new value without causing infinite recursion ?

```
public delegate void NameChangedHandler( object sender, EventArgs e );

event NameChangedHandler NameChanged;

public String Name
{
    get;
    set { Name = value; NameChanged(this, null); } // Recursion ?
}
```

Comment: "but I do not want to have a non-public field to store its value" -- you can't do that. You have to have a field to store its value.

Comment: Thanks. So in the end I must have to duplicate every property that I want to raise events ? That's not going to make things easier to maintain.

Comment: "I do not want to have a non-public field to store its value." Where DO you want it set then? It can't go anywhere else, while also maintaining the definition of what a property is.

Comment: @Quantic No, you don't.  A setter can do whatever it wants in its body; it's just a method, functionally.  If you want the setter to just not store the value, or to store it somewhere other than a field (say, a file, database, registry, etc.) then you can do that.

Comment: @Quantic In my case I do want to store the given value into the property, which is why he said that.

Comment: @Servy you are right and I understand, I should have been more clear in my comment. Really it's this part of his question I should have quoted: "how can I assign the property with the new value (without a field to store its value)" -- answer: you can't do that.

Comment: @Quantic My question was more like "How can I store the new value of "Name" within "Name" **itself**, without calling the setter recursively, and without having a second duplicated field for that."

Comment: @Virus721 Yes, that is a much clearer question.  You should edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [...] but I do not want to have a non-public field to store its value.

This requirement can't be met. Even auto-properties have a `private` field backing their values. They're still created during C# compilation. And, anwyay, you can't mix auto-properties and properties with body in the *getter* or *setter*.

Maybe you can be interested in some open source project I created and published some months ago called [*TrackerDog*](http://matiasfidemraizer.com/trackerdog/html/0e46d6ac-6f64-4d54-98fd-3813df42cb8e.htm) which can turn any object into a change-trackable one. And [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) is auto-implemented during run-time using proxies.

This way, you don't need to switch to non-auto-properties and you can still get the event injected and each *set* of properties within a given object will raise `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event.

For example, given the following class:

```
public class User
{
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual byte Age { get; set; }
}
```

...you can turn an instance of `User` into change-trackable as follows:

```
User user = new User().AsTrackable();
// or
User user = Trackable.Of<User>();
```

...and now that `User` instance implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
INotifyPropertyChanged userWhichCanHookChangeHandlers =
                            (INotifyPropertyChanged)user;



userWhichCanHookChangeHandlers.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
     string propertyName = e.PropertyName;
};
```

Check project's full [how-to to get further details](http://matiasfidemraizer.com/trackerdog/html/52e40f26-3dfe-47e0-adf1-09233e98f42e.htm).

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "you can't mix auto-properties and properties with body in the getter or setter" ? I only have one property here.

Comment: @Virus721 Matias means you can't have a simple "get;" without a body and have a "set" with a body. So if you want to do... *stuff* with your "set" body you'll have to do *something* (get the private variable) with the "get."

Comment: @Virus721 Check my updated answer. Maybe my project, TrackerDog can assist you a lot in your underlying issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your Setter to not actually Set anything, you CAN do that. (Not sure why you want to, but, nothing is stopping you.)

```
public String Name
{
    get { return _Name; }
    set { NameChanged(this, null); } 
}
```

That is valid and will compile just fine.

`value` is nothing more than a parameter to your setter method, and just like with any other method, you can choose to do absolutely nothing with your parameter(s).

Comment: Thanks but I do want to store the value, otherwise I would just create a NameChanged method.

Comment: This *does not* compile. "Error CS0501 'Program.Name.get' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial". You have to either get rid of the getter, or declare a body that returns a valid `string` value.

Comment: @Quantic: My bad, blindly copied from OP.